# How to fire a network request in one screen and getting result eventually in VIPER architecture?

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

I need to call a 'function' that makes some network requests and data processing, which may take some time.

So, almost as soon as my app launches I call my function to have the response ready when the user gets to the screen where will be needed.

Where/How would you fire the network request, and how would you notify the eventual presenter that you got a response or didn't?

Comment: Get the response from network in a separate NSObject class or normal class and make use of a Protocol from created class to main class where data is to be shown Means when Execution of request is done then Views will be reloaded in Main

Comment: Would that be in conformance with the VIPER architecture? Which would be the 'main class'?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://theswiftdev.com/the-ultimate-viper-architecture-tutorial

- The network request & asynchronous response would be in the *interactor* zone of VIPER, because that is where all sensor, database, and network operations reside, which of course includes all extraction from the fields from packets or formatted bytestreams (which might be a tiny portion of what might be called “data processing” in OP).
- The data retrieved & structure thereof would be in the *entity* zone of VIPER.
- The ‘business logic’ of the main portion of “data processing” in OP would be in the *presenter* zone of VIPER, operating on the aforementioned entities in the entity zone.

It seems that some stimulus exists somewhere (e.g., in the UI in the *view* zone of VIPER) to trigger the action that eventually ends up being the network request over in interactor zone.  If that stimulus originates in the UI, there would naturally be a flow of inter-VIPER-zone synchronous messaging from view to presenter to interactor so as to initiate the asynchronous network request.  The asynchrony (as well as everything else regarding outgoing & incoming network traffic) would be handled within the internal-matters guts of interactor zone.

This answer speaks of VIPER 1st & foremost without mentioning Swift or iOS on purpose, because the VIPER architectural zones & the messaging between them should have no knowledge of for which platform this build of the app is targeted.

1. An iOS app would swap in the iOS-/SwiftUI-centric view zone at build-time.  A MacOS app would swap in the Cocoa-/SwiftUI-centric view zone at build-time.  An Android app would swap in the JNIing-to-Kotlin/Java view zone at build-time.  A UWP app would swap in the C++/WinRT or C#/WinRT view zone at build-time.
2. Likewise, an iOS or MacOS app would swap in the WebKit-framework-centric interactor zone at build-time.  An Android app would swap in the WebView-centric interactor zone at build-time.  A UWP app would swap in the Windows.Web.Http-centric interactor zone at build-time.